# Reading the state just after writing into it in the same chaincode

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have setup the Fabric as per the instruction using docker and everything works fine. I have a chaincode which stores a value in the world state which I can read afterwards using a query method.

My scenario is something like this: I submit multiple separate requests within a short period of time to store different data in the world state. Within each request I need to read the data just submitted previously. However, I am unable to read the most recently submitted data.

My understanding is that it might be because those data might not be stored in the blockchain yet and hence they cannot be read. With this understanding, I introduced a sleep function to sleep for a few seconds to give enough time for the previously submitted data to be included in the blockchain. However, this approach was not successful.

So I am wondering if there is any way to read the previous data just after storing the subsequent data.

Thanks,
Ripul

Answer (score 1):

Waiting a few seconds in the chaincode would not be sufficient. Data that is 'written' in chaincode is not yet committed to the database, it is only a proposal to write something to the database at that point. Only committed data is read back in chaincode.  Therefore after you make an update in chaincode and get the proposal response, you must submit the transaction to ordering. It may take a few seconds for orderer to cut the block, distribute it to peers, and have peers commit the data. Only then can the data be read back in chaincode.

If you must read the data that you just wrote within the same chaincode function, then you will need to keep a map of the data that has been written and retrieve the value from the map rather than from the committed database.